# Populating html sidebar with js variable data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a fast learning beginner with Google Sheets Script. In the apps I've done so far the sidebars I've made have included buttons and text, but nothing passed from variables. I'll note that I understand Javascript reasonably well, but haven't branched into jquery as yet, though I have a good book on the topic.

In this case I have variable values taken from two different spreadsheets that I'd like passed to the sidebar so that the user can view data and set an appointment.

My .gs code:(This is server side code)

```js
function apptSidebar2() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('setApptsPage2')
      .setTitle('Counselor Connect Easy!')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function setAppts2() {
    //get all the data for client appointment
    var setupSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Setup');
    var shID=setupSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
    var feedSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(shID);
    var dataSheet = feedSheet.getSheetByName('StudentData'); 
    
    var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
    var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
    for(var i=lastRow;i>0;i--) {
      if(dataSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue()==thisID) {
        var clientData = dataSheet.getRange(i,1,1,lastColumn).getValues();
        }
    } 
    var SID = thisID;
    var SLN = clientData[0][1];
    var SFN = clientData[0][2];
    var b1r = clientData[0][3].toString();
    var b1t = clientData[0][4].toString();
    var b1c = clientData[0][5].toString();
    var SB1 = b1r+" "+b1t+" "+b1c;
    
    var b2r = clientData[0][6].toString();
    var b2t = clientData[0][7].toString();
    var b2c = clientData[0][8].toString();
    var SB2 = b2r+" "+b2t+" "+b2c;
    
    var b3r = clientData[0][9].toString();
    var b3t = clientData[0][10].toString();
    var b3c = clientData[0][11].toString();
    var SB3 = b3r+" "+b3t+" "+b3c;
    
    var b4r = clientData[0][12].toString();
    var b4t = clientData[0][13].toString();
    var b4c = clientData[0][14].toString();
    var SB4 = b4r+" "+b4t+" "+b4c;
    
    var b5r = clientData[0][15].toString();
    var b5t = clientData[0][16].toString();
    var b5c = clientData[0][17].toString();
    var SB5 = b5r+" "+b5t+" "+b5c;
    
    var b6r = clientData[0][18].toString();
    var b6t = clientData[0][19].toString();
    var b6c = clientData[0][20].toString();
    var SB6 = b6r+" "+b6t+" "+b6c;

    apptSidebar2(); 
}
```

And my html for the sidebar, which I suspect is grossly uninformed in terms of how I need to connect the two. For all I know I'm closer than I think:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function getStudent() {
  if(!document.getElementById) return;
  var apptDiv2 = document.getElementById("appt2");
 }
 </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="padding: 10px; text-align:center;">
    <div id="appt2">
    <b>Student Data</b>
    <p id="name">Student Name</p>
    <p id = "id">nnnnn</p>
    <p id = "reason">Why</p>
    <p id = "notes">More why</p>
    <p id = "blk1">Block 1</p>
    <p id = "blk2">Block 2</p>
    <p id = "blk3">Block 3</p>
    <p id = "blk4">Block 4</p>
    <p id = "blk5">Block 5</p>
    <p id = "blk6">Block 6</p>
    
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="click to choose date">
  </div>
</div>

  <div style=
        "width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%; 
        text-align:center;
        background-color:black;
        text-color:white;">
        <p><a href="http://www.fastadmin.solutions" target="blank"><b>©FastAdmin Solutions</b></a></p>
</div>  
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly set variables in the as-constructed sidebar, you'll need to create an `HtmlTemplate` from the sidebar's HTML file, pass that to the `setAppts` function, set those values on the template object, and then return the "filled" template to the calling function, to be built into an `HtmlOutput` and displayed:

```
function getApptSidebarOutput() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("a filename");
  fillAppts_(template);
  return template.evaluate();
}
function fillAppts_(theTemplate) {
  theTemplate.someVarName = some value;
  theTemplate.otherVar = some other value;
  ...
  return theTemplate;
}
```

In your HTML file, these variables can be used directly as `someVarName` and `otherVar`.

Recommended reading:

- [template guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Adding variables to templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates)

Note that depending on what this data is and who is using it, you may be better off with a fully async design, where the sidebar is constructed without this data, and queries for up-to-date info periodically (like right before submitting an appointment request, or otherwise every 5-10 minutes). The idea being, schedule availabilities change, but the sidebar can be left open.

Comment: thanks. At first glance I'm having a hard time making sense of this, and I've seen the documentation. I'm going to work in my sandbox on some simple applications of this so I can get a feel for where this leads me. I appreciate the direction.

Comment: I've been reading and re-reading this and the linked documentation, and it's starting to sink in, and I can now see where your code up there fits in the scheme of things. I think most of the data queried will be good for most of each day, downloaded from a database. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

## Not meant to be a comprehensive answer:

**You could change this:**

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

**To something like this**

HTML(clientside):

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler('insertHtmlIntoADiv')
    .getDesiredDataInHtmlFormat();
  } );
     function insertHtmlIntoADiv(hl){
     $('#mydiv').html(hl);
     }
  </script>
```

CODE(ServerSide):

```
getDesiredDataInHtmlFormat(){
//generate html integrated with wanted data and store it in a string and return it.  It will be picked up by the success handler.
}
```

> For more info on `google.script.run` look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: I wasn't clear at all,I think. I'm trying  to get SID, SLN, SFN, SB1, SB2, etc from  the javascript to the sidebar, preferably with js. The jquery in there for the datepicker was from  a library, and works.

Comment: I believe it's in setAppts2 which I believe you say is .gs code.  Yes? No?.  If yes then  it could be something simple like `'<br />SID=' +  SID + '<br />SLN=' + SIN....`. GS code is on the server and your sidebar is actually html is on the client.